# $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}~dx$ without trigonometric functions

Tags: integration

I have tried to calculate this integral
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}~dx$$
with the instruction to do it with this
$$t = x + \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}$$
This is the right answer:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}~dx = \ln\left(\frac{|x + \sqrt{a^2 + x^2}|}{|a|}\right) + C$$
But I got wrong answer (in yellow)

[image]

Where do I wrong?

Comment: Please remove the image and add your working in using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting images which cannot be searched and may not be readable for users who use screen readers.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The image, which shows the work and where the error is, was removed.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is also right. Only difference are the constant term $-\log|a|$ and since there is integration constant $C$, to answers are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $t=x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$, gives $(t-x)^{2}=x^2+a^2$. This simplifies to $t^2-2tx-a^2=0$. From here we can replace $\mathrm dx$ in terms of $\mathrm dt$, and evaluate the integral.

Comment: how can I replace dx in terms of dt, and evaluate the integral?

Comment: Since $x=(t^{2}-a^{2})/2t$, so we can rewrite $\mathrm dx$ in terms of $a$, $t$ and $\mathrm dt$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct except for the absence of a constant of integration.  $\log(|a|)$, in the given answer, is simply a constant that can be rolled into the constant of integration.

Here is another approach:

Let $u^2=x^2+a^2$; then $u\,\mathrm{d}u=x\,\mathrm{d}x$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{u}
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{x}\tag{1a}\\
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}(x+u)}{x+u}\tag{1b}\\[3pt]
&=\log(x+u)+C\tag{1c}\\[6pt]
&=\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)+C\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: $u\,\mathrm{d}u=x\,\mathrm{d}x$
$\text{(1b)}$: $\frac ab=\frac cd\implies\frac ab=\frac cd=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$
$\text{(1c)}$: integrate
$\text{(1d)}$: back substitute